# C++ binary input as a string to a decimal

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that takes a binary number input as a string and will only accept 1's or 0's if not there should be an error message displayed. Then it should go through a loop digit by digit to convert the binary number as a string to decimal. I cant seem to get it right I have the fact that it will only accept 1's or 0's correct. But then when it gets into the calculations something messes up and I cant seem to get it correct. Currently this is the closest I believe I have to getting it working. could anyone give me a hint or help me with what i am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string a;

int input();

int main()
{
    input();
    int decimal, x= 0, length, total = 0;
    length = a.length();
    // atempting to make it put the digits through a formula backwords.
    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
// Trying to make it only add the 2^x if the number is 1
        if (a[i] = '1')
        {
            //should make total equal to the old total plus 2^x if a[i] = 1
            total = total + pow(x,2);
        }
        //trying to let the power start at 0 and go up each run of the loop
        x++;
    }

    cout << endl << total;
    int stop;
    cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}

int input()
{
    int x, x2, count, repeat = 0;

    while (repeat == 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter a string representing a binary number => ";
        cin >> a;
        count = a.length();

        for (x = 0; x < count; x++)
        {

            if (a[x] != '0' && a[x] != '1')
            {
                cout << a << " is not a string representing a binary number>" << endl;
                repeat = 0;
                break;

            }
            else
                repeat = 1;



        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using standard library, `pow(x,2)` is not `2^x` but `x^2` (operator `^` means power here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't think that `pow` suits for integer calculation. In this case, you can use shift operator.
- `a[i] = '1'` sets the value of `a[i]` to `'1'` and return `'1'`, which is always true.
- You shouldn't access `a[length]`, which should be meaningless.

fixed code:

```
int main()
{
    input();
    int decimal, x= 0, length, total = 0;
    length = a.length();
    // atempting to make it put the digits through a formula backwords.
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
// Trying to make it only add the 2^x if the number is 1
        if (a[i] == '1')
        {
            //should make total equal to the old total plus 2^x if a[i] = 1
            total = total + (1 << x);
        }
        //trying to let the power start at 0 and go up each run of the loop
        x++;
    }

    cout << endl << total;
    int stop;
    cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str{ "10110011" }; // max length can be sizeof(int) X 8
    int dec = 0, mask = 1;

    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == '1') {
            dec |= mask;
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }

    cout << "Decimal number is: " << dec;


    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple misstages in your code.

1. Your `for`-loop should start at `i = length - 1` instead of `i = length`.
2. `a[i] = '1'` sets `a[i]` to `'1'` and does not compare it.
3. `pow(x,2)` means [image: x^2] and not [image: 2^x]. `pow` is also not designed for integer operations. Use `2*2*...` or `1<<e` instead.

Also there are shorter ways to achieve it. Here is a example how I would do it:

```
std::size_t fromBinaryString(const std::string &str)
{
    std::size_t result = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        // '0' - '0' == 0 and '1' - '0' == 1.
        // If you don't want to assume that, you can use if or switch
        result = (result << 1) + str[i] - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for binary strings up to 32 bits.  Swap out integer for long to get 64 bits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getBinaryString(int value, unsigned int length, bool reverse) {
    string output = string(length, '0');
    if (!reverse) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if ((value & (1 << i)) != 0) {
                output[i] = '1';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if ((value & (1 << (length - i - 1))) != 0) {
                output[i] = '1';
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

unsigned long getInteger(const string& input, size_t lsbindex, size_t msbindex) {
    unsigned long val = 0;
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    if (lsbindex > msbindex) {
        size_t length = lsbindex - msbindex;
        for (size_t i = msbindex; i <= lsbindex; i++, offset++) {
            if (input[i] == '1') {
                val |= (1 << (length - offset));
            }
        }
    }
    else { //lsbindex < msbindex
        for (size_t i = lsbindex; i <= msbindex; i++, offset++) {
            if (input[i] == '1') {
                val |= (1 << offset);
            }
        }
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    int value = 23;
    cout << value << ": " << getBinaryString(value, 5, false) << endl;
    string str = "01011";
    cout << str << ": " << getInteger(str, 1, 3) << endl;
}
```